# How to restrict edit text when entered value is exceeds the compare value?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have an edit text in list view custom row. If i try to enter some value i am comparing that value in text Watcher. Now if entered value is exceeds the compare value that digit i don't want to allow that character but edittext in edit mode or focus.
this is my code

```
holder.etCredit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            creditNoteBean = data.get(holder.refPosition);
            String availCredit = holder.txtAvailableCredit.getText().toString();
            String entrVal = s.toString();
            if (entrVal != null && !entrVal.isEmpty()) {
                if (Double.parseDouble(availCredit) < Double.parseDouble(entrVal)) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Exceeding available credit ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    creditNoteBean.setSelectedCreditNotePrice(s.toString());
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found solution how to restrict edittext field comparing with some value

```
 @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            creditNoteBean = data.get(holder.refPosition);

            String availCredit = holder.txtAvailableCredit.getText().toString();
            String entrVal = s.toString();

            if (entrVal != null && !entrVal.isEmpty()) {
                if (Double.parseDouble(availCredit) < Double.parseDouble(entrVal)) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Exceeding available credit ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    holder.etCreditNoteAmount.setText(entrVal.substring(0, entrVal.length() - 1));
                } else {

                    creditNoteBean.setSelectedCreditNotePrice(s.toString());
                }
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the length of value in text Watcher and put the condition on the Edit Text with maximum length of value in text Watcher.

```
EditText et = new EditText(this);
int max = 10;    
et.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(max)});
```

or if the length of value in text Watcher is fixed than you can add the attribute `android:maxLength="value in text Watcher"`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: nice tip...it helped me.